# Refactoring: How can I contain long names in a code area of 120 spaces?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, refactoring

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.1.0 and I am refactoring/reordering my source code so to make that more readable. I am using a code area with a "right margin" of 120 spaces (that is, I have 120 characters of space to write the code).

The following image should make it clear what I mean:

[image]
*Note*: the image is from the NetBeans IDE software.

Now, in my source code I have long constant and method names that come out from that limit of 120 spaces. For example:

```
a_my_very_long_variable_name_stated_just_for_testing_purposes = A_MY_VERY_LONG_CONSTANT_NAME_STATED_JUST_FOR_TESTING_PURPOSES

a_my_very_long_method_name_stated_just_for_testing_purposes(a_my_very_long_parameter_name_stated_just_for_testing_purposes_1, a_my_very_long_parameter_name_stated_just_for_testing_purposes_2)
```

**How should I refactor above codes? That is, how can I contain those in 120 spaces? What are best Ruby practices for these issues?**

*P.S.*: I have considered the possibility of shortening constant and method names but at the moment is not applicable.

Comment: What are you testing this way? Ability of editor to handle long strings?

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev - *No*. I would like to rewrite the code so to contain that in 120 spaces in a *readable* way. Maybe a good practice is to use parenthesis and to go to a new line, but I don't know if it is recommended.

Comment: Use shorter names. Names that long are unreadable, a little moderation will serve you better.

Comment: I'm with mu. Readability is not longer names, but more descriptive ones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write it like this:

```
a_my_very_long_variable_name_stated_just_for_testing_purposes = 
    A_MY_VERY_LONG_CONSTANT_NAME_STATED_JUST_FOR_TESTING_PURPOSES

a_my_very_long_method_name_stated_just_for_testing_purposes(
    a_my_very_long_parameter_name_stated_just_for_testing_purposes_1,
    a_my_very_long_parameter_name_stated_just_for_testing_purposes_2
)
```

If the last token on the line is an operator or a comma you can break statement into multiple lines. Alternatively, you can use `\` to continue on the next line.